ASP.NET Core MVC : convert formatted currency string in front-end to decimal in controller using binding
I have an example class like this:
public class TestClass
{
    [Precision(18,2)]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}

In the frontend, Amount is treated as a string with the following format: $120,555.35. So, when I submit the form how do I auto-convert this string format to decimal format?
I believe it should reformat before the datatype validation.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] TestClass request)
{
    // ...
}

Appreciate any help, thanks.

You can custom model binder like below to achieve your requirement:
public class CustomDecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Remove currency symbols and commas, then parse
        value = value.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");

        if (decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal decimalValue))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(decimalValue);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, "Invalid decimal value");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Apply the binder to the Amount property:
public class TestClass
{
    [Precision(18, 2)]
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomDecimalModelBinder))]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}

Reference:Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core

Yeah but if we're going to do it we should do it properly, this is English countries value = value.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""); the OP or any viewer will probably want to keep the numbers, comma's and dots plus negative sign: Regex.Replace(value, @"[^\d\.,-]", ""); Now I personally wouldn't do this RegEx as then I'd need to manage every international currency myself, instead I use this DataType and I've had decades of coding experience in Finance using it https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11531/Money-DataType

what if i didn't  want my class library project refer to netcore.mvc modelbinding? currently, I put the class inside this project. i hv another webapp project that consume/take reference from this class library. Thank you.

Hi @Topik, it is impossible. If you do not add the reference, how is your asp.net core project know where is the TestClass from?

Hi @Rena,thank you for  the answer. is it possible to use jsonconverter instead?

Hi @Topik, Of course you can. But if you use JsonConverter, the parameter you pass should be from Body instead of from form.
